# How can I delete my printer from Ubuntu?

Tags: 12.04, uninstall, password, sudo

Using 12.04 my printer a canon ip2600 will not print.

SystemSettings/printers shows it as installed, connected to local host, enabled, accepting jobs, shared and allowing printing for everyone. Yet it does not print.

I have tried to remove it but get a request for user name and password which I enter (I only have one password) but the password is listed as incorrect.

I need a sudo command which I can use to delete the printer so I can attempt to re-install it. As it is the printer is useless and I can not even uninstall it.

Comment: How are you trying to remove it? Are you using the command line or a GUI method?

Comment: I tried uninstall using GUI but it will not accept my password. I need a sudo command.

Comment: But are you a sudo user? Because, you need enter a sudo password. If the GUI method doesn't work, the command line neither

Comment: I am a sudo user, I am a member of groups lp, root, sudo and dialout. I can use sudo commands but the Printer GUI asks for user name and password but rejects them. That is why I want a sudo command so I can bypass the GUI.

Comment: To further clarify: I am the only user of this computer. When I enter a sudo command I enter my password, as requested, and the command executes. However the SystemSettingg/printers GUI rejects my user name and password.

Comment: Somewhat solved.   OKAY, I added myself to group lpadmin and was able to delete the printer with the GUI. Now I have NO printer installed. Next I will try to reinstall the Canon printer, but not today. Enough fiddling, it is time for a coffee break.

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! I'm glade that you find the solution. Please, create a new answer to tell us how did you resolved the problem. That is how the site work. Is more useful than show it into a comment. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

I solved the problem by adding my user name to the "lpadmin" group. Since I somehow was not in that group I was not allowed to change anything related to the printer. Once I was in the group I was able to delete the printer. Now all I have to do is re-install the printer.